# Start an Activiy from an AsyncTask (PostExecute) in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-context

I read lots of questions about it and anyone fix my problem. I have an AsyncTask where a new activity must be started. The code is the following:

```
public class UpdateCatalog extends AsyncTask <Void,Integer,Void> {

private Context context;
private LoadActivity activity;

public UpdateCatalog(LoadActivity activity) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = this.activity.getApplicationContext();
} 
   .
   .
   .

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
    // Update your views here
    LoadActivity.progressStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, DownloadImages.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
}
```

The call to this AsincTask is in the Activity which started the AsincTask and is like following:

```
   public class LoadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView txtStatus;
public static ProgressBar progressStatus;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load);
    txtStatus  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressStatus);
    progressStatus = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    if(CheckCatalog()){
        ShowUpdateDialog();
    }
    else
        new UpdateCatalog(this).execute();
}
```

The error is the following:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {es.aplicaciones.alvaro.entrelazadas/es.aplicaciones.alvaro.entrelazadas.DownloadImages};
```

The DownloadImages.class is already created. So I think it is not the problem. I try with other ways pasing the context as parameter but it still not working. 
Please can you help me?

Comment: have you declared your activity in manifest

Comment: check your manifest whether you given LoadActivity.

Comment: Thanks, it was the problem, I waste around 2 hours trying to fix it  and the solution was very simple but i didn't think about it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you have to declare each activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file :)

```
<activity android:name=".DownloadImages" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the problem, I waste around 2 hours trying to fix it  and the solution was very simple but i didn't think about it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file.
If your `DownloadImages` class is in the "base" package which is declared in manifest file then add the activity with *.ClassName*

```
<application> 
....
     <activity android:name=".DownloadImages" />
</application>
```

else
 write full path to your `DownloadImages` class.

```
 <application> 
    ....
         <activity android:name="com.example.path.DownloadImages" />
 </application>
```